# Fire event when html content change

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I want to fire an action when there is change in `html` content. Below code changes html content of `myId` element, when `click` on button, so there is change in html content of `myId` now I want to fire another action say `console.log("myalert")`.

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="buttonid" value="click">
    <div id = "myId">
    </div>
</body>
<script>
var button = document.getElementById("buttonid");
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log("alert");
        document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML = '<input type="button" id="button3" value="click2">'
    });

var button2 = document.getElementById("myId");
button2.addEventListener("change", function () {
        console.log("myalert");        
    });    
</script>
</html>
```

How can I achieve my requirement?

**Note:** I don't want to use `jQuery`.

Comment: Why do you put content outside `body`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Comment: @DanielLisik it doesn't matter, I have updated my code can you have you have a look again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real event for that. You could however resolve this by listening for changes in an interval loop. I wouldn't really recommend it, but it's not up to me to decide what you use in the end. It would be something in the lines of:

```
var myIdContent = document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML;
setInterval(function(){
  if(myIdContent !== document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML){
    myIdContent = document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML;
    // Element has changed, do some modifications here
  }
}, 1000); // Lower number for shorter intervals
```

However this could become terribly slow when the contents of the div grows. A better way would be to invoke an event or 'change' function whenever you change html from javascript. You have more stuff to write, but also more control over when change events occur.

Question with answers that don't involve comparing contents:
[Detect changes in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom)

Comment: I don't want to use `setInterval`. Is there any other way?

Comment: Well then, there's no real easy ready made implementation of DOM manipulation events. You should check here, and be willing to get your hands dirty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom